# Code for type="h" in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

This may sound really simple but I'm trying to find the equivalent code to `plot(x,y, type="h")`
as a qplot code.   I already have:

```
qplot(x,y,data,geom="point")
```

Comment: Just curious why this question was up-voted twice!

Comment: it admittedly doesn't show much resource effort, or a reproducible example, *but* it is a question that I think a variety of users would be interested in, and there is not in fact (I think) an obvious answer lying around.

Answer (score 12):

It's a little clunky, but I think you need `geom_segment()`.

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:5,y=c(0.1,0.4,0.8,0.2,0.9))
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x=x,xend=x,y=0,yend=y,data=d,geom="segment")
## or equivalently
ggplot(d,aes(x=x,xend=x,y=0,yend=y))+geom_segment()
```

This gives (y label adapted):
[image: Resulting plot with ggplot2]

In contrast, using the histogram with `stat=identity`:

```
qplot(data = d, x=x, y=y, stat="identity")
```

gives:

[image]

For completeness, the `plot` with `type='h'` looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the answer of user12202013 is totally correct, but if you want to use qplot you can do it as follows:

```
qplot(data = data, x = x, binwidth = 0.5)
```

But, I think, if you need some help on R, you should go to Stackoverflow

Comment: @BenBolker, the main problem is - we don't know what the data are!!

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question: OP wants "type='h'" like behaviour of plot, given separate x and y values. The code here gives a figure of the occurence of the frequency of the x values (i.e. a histogram).

Answer (score 0):

With ggplot you only need a data frame with a vector of observations, not the count for each value.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x)) + geom_histogram()
```